# use nhibernate ResultTransformer

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am using Nhibernate last version in my MVC project

I want to make a query on an object type names "Person" but person has many properties. In one of my queries I'd better not to have most of these properties. 
Here is Person:

```
public partial class Person
{
    virtual public User User { get; set; }
    virtual public string FirstName { get; set; }
    virtual public string LastName { get; set; }
    virtual public int Gender { get; set; }
    virtual public Contact Contact { get; set; }
    virtual public BirthCertificate PersonBirthCertificate { get; set; }
}
```

In the query I just want first name and last name of the person.

So I decided to use ResultTransformer and implement it like this:

```
public class PersonResultTransformer : IResultTransformer
{
    private Type result;
    private PropertyInfo[] properties;

    #region IResultTransformer Members

    public IList TransformList(IList collection)
    {
        return collection;
    }
    public PersonResultTransformer (Type result, params string[] names)
    {
        this.result = result;
        List<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>();
        foreach (string name in names)
        {
            props.Add(result.GetProperty(name));
        }
        properties = props.ToArray();
    }

    public object TransformTuple(object[] tuple, string[] aliases)
    {
        object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < tuple.Length; i++)
        {
            var t = properties[i].Name;

            var value = tuple[i].GetType().GetProperty(t).GetValue(tuple[i], null);
            instance.GetType().GetProperty(t).SetValue(instance, value, null);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

and for getting want I want with linq query :

```
var person = Repository<Person>.Find(p => p.LastName.Equals("Nadal")
   , new PersonResultTransformer (typeof(Person), "FirstName", "LastName"));

////////////////

public IQueryable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression, IResultTransformer transformer)
{
    return Session.CreateCriteria<T>().SetResultTransformer(transformer).List<T>()
        .AsQueryable().Where(expression);

}
```

Is it OK? can it be more customized? do I use it correctly?

It seems that it has a big problem: it gets all persons's first name and last name and then select from them, those having last name="nadal", and the performance is not good at all

Answer (score 4):

first you have to delegate to a query which understands expressions

```
using NHibernate.Linq;

public IQueryable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
{
    return Session.Query<T>().Where(expression);
}
```

then you can

```
var personDTOs = Repository<Person>.Find(p => p.LastName.Equals("Nadal"))
    .Select(person => new { person.FirstName, person.LastName });
```

you can shorten the resulttransformer a lot, but you cant use it with Linq2NHibernate.

```
public class PersonResultTransformer : IResultTransformer
{
    private Type result;
    private List<PropertyInfo> properties = new List<PropertyInfo>();

    public IList TransformList(IList collection)
    {
        return collection;
    }
    public PersonResultTransformer (Type result, params string[] names)
    {
        this.result = result;
        foreach (string name in names)
        {
            properties.Add(result.GetProperty(name));
        }
    }

    public object TransformTuple(object[] tuple, string[] aliases)
    {
        object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < tuple.Length; i++)
        {
            properties[i].SetValue(instance, tuple[i], null);
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this is a solution but I want to use result transformer,, consider that I want to learn how to use it but I'm confused ,if its possible tell me how can I do it with linq to hibernate using result transformer

Comment: is there any way like :Session.Query<T>() .Where(expression)..SetResultTransformer(transformer)  ?

Comment: Simply projecting into the PersonDTO object as suggested will cause only those two properties to come back.  Another option might be to change your mapping so the Person object is comprised of several Value Types, mark those value types as lazily loaded then include hints to force them to come back in the query.  If your goal is to learn how and where to use ResultTransformers this might not be a good case.

Answer (score 0):

You use `Session.CreateCriteria<T>()` but you do not [add any criteria](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-narrowing) to it. So, the query is executed without criteria and then transformed and filtered.

You have to find a way to add your specifications to the `Find` method in a way that Nhibernate's `ICriteria` can handle, or use Linq to Nhibernate (beware of some issues though!).

Comment: without using create criteria, and just using find expersion coulde I do it?

Comment: how can I do it with linq to hibernate?

Comment: Linq to Nhibernate is part of the Nhibernate source since (I think) 3.2, so it is ready to use. There are many posts at StackOverflow about it and you could take a look [here](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/16/using-the-new-linq-to-nh-provider-and-migrating-from-the-old-one.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong - but I think you're overdoing this.

You could more easily utilize lazy loading to not fetch the properties you don't need.

Comment: its just a sample and I want to know if my kind of using result transformer is ok or not,,I know that I can use lazy property